# Generate Network Report

Tags: windows, software-development, networking, network-monitor

Currently at my IT firm we are performing proactive maintenance on each of our clients servers, we're checking *disk space, event viewer logs, OS updates, uptime, Anti-Virus updates, RAID Health* and many many more. Then placing this into a word doc saying if each item is okay or not.

The problem we are facing is that we're starting to get so many clients it's becoming very time consuming and costly to manually have to do this.

Was wondering if anyone had any recommendations on some type of software that might be able to do this? Or would we be better off creating our own custom software? 
It would need to be reasonably customizable. We have previously looked into SpiceWorks and Kaseya, however it does not appear to do the majority of what we are looking for.

Thanks guys!

Comment: What operating system(s) are the computers using? Do you have the IP address of all computers, or do you need automatic discovery on the network? Do you have all credentials?

Comment: Most will only be Servers, generally 2008R2. But there are some 2008, 2012, and client PC's vary from Vista to 8. All IP addresses for the PC's are dynamic so automatic discovery would be good, however not necessary as most are only be done on the Servers. We do have all credentials, all PC's are on the domain.

Comment: Can't you install an agent on the clients (be it PC, server, etc.) that 'phones home' every X hours or day and inserts the information into a database? There are COTS solutions for this like SpiceWorks, ManageEngine, etc. If those tools don't include the metrics you're looking for, you can use them to deploy your custom scripts to run.

Comment: @Skram: Feel free to post your knowledge as an answer.

Comment: @user3045068: Are you OK with installing software on each computer?

Comment: Not using it myself, and not being really familiar with I cannot make it an answer, but [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) and its successors seem like a good fit here (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios)). *Nagios* works cross-platform and is highly customizable: there are tons of plugins already available, and you can easily provide your own to make it fit all your needs.